# CentOS 7 - Impossible to install PHP 7.3

Tags: php, centos, centos7, yum, php-7.3

I want to enable **php73** as default version and install all packages related to it. So I did:

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
```

And then:

```
$ sudo yum install php php-pecl-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysqlnd php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo php-common php-xml php-fpm php-mbstring php-bcmath php-soap php-oci8
```

Right after, I can see that it wants to install **PHP 8.0** (*remi-php80*, which breaks my project dependencies):

```
Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================
 Package              Arch             Version                             Repository            Size
======================================================================================================
Installing:
 php                  x86_64           8.0.0~beta4-2.el7.remi              remi-php80           3.4 M
Installing for dependencies:
 php-cli              x86_64           8.0.0~beta4-2.el7.remi              remi-php80           5.3 M
 php-common           x86_64           8.0.0~beta4-2.el7.remi              remi-php80           1.2 M
 php-sodium           x86_64           8.0.0~beta4-2.el7.remi              remi-php80            74 k
```

How can I enable & force installation of **PHP 7.3** on Centos 7?

> I want to avoid doing it manually like:
> `$ sudo yum install php73 php73-php-cli php73-php-fpm`

Comment: One of the steps on the [config wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) is to see if you have [priorities](https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) enabled, and if so, "ensure remi-php73 have higher priority (a lower value) than base and updates". Not sure about your install, but maybe check that?

Comment: On CentOS 8 and CentOS Stream just switch the module stream branch as described here: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_8&p=php&f=2

CentOS 7 should also have official PHP versions as SCL but I'm not using that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want **PHP 7.3** you must only enable "**remi-php73**" repository (and "**remi-safe**", which is enabled by default).

According to yum output in your question "**remi-php80**" is wrongly enabled. You can wheck which repositories are enabled using

```
# yum repolist
```

For a proper repository configuration, see the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

```
# yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
# yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
# yum-config-manager --enable remi-safe
```

About [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/mcrypt) extension, I recommend you get rid of it, see [About libmcrypt and php-mcrypt](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt)

And I think you don't need both **php** (mod_php for Apache HTTP Server) and **php-fpm**

And for **php-oci8**, I recommend you read [Installation of Oracle extensions for PHP](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2020/05/18/Installation-of-Oracle-extensions-for-PHP)

Comment: Wow, `yum repolist` just made things clear. Why this is not at every tutorial? There was both enabled **remi-php73** and **remi-php80**, then I disabled the last one (`yum-config-manager --disable remi-php80`) and everything worked fine.

Comment: And also thanks for the trick between **php** and **php-fpm**, I didn't know about it. I only need **php-fpm** to use with **nginx**. About **php-oci8**, I am fine.